# How to set element's :hover state in Chrome dev tools and edit child's style

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, google-chrome-devtools

Suppose we have this style:

```
.parent .child { ... }

.parent:hover .child { ... }
```

Both selectors set style for child elements.

What I would like is to edit the second style.

1. I click on `.parent` and set `:hover` state in Chrome developer tools
2. Click on a `.child` element to get to child's style but...

When I click on `.child` the hover on parent is gone (because it's now set on `.child`).

<sup>This works in Firebug though but I need it in Chrome...</sup>

> Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**: Chrome now has the following new hotness:

1. Right-click the child element and choose Inspect Element

   - *Chrome will open the Elements view with the item selected*
2. In the Elements view, right-click the parent element and choose "Force Element State ▶ :hover"
   [image: Screenshot of "Force Element State" menu]
3. Select the child element in the Elements view again.

---

*Older, valid-but-obnoxious technique follows:*

Tested with [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tq5gJ/1/):

1. Hover the child element itself (which also hovers the parent).
2. Right-click the child.
3. **Using the keyboard** (not mouse) move the context menu selection down to "Inspect Element" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   - *Hurrah, the CSS rule for the hovered parent and selected child is available*
4. Edit the rule. *(You may move the mouse to do this; the item will be unhovered, but the CSS rule with the `:hover` in it will not go away.)*
5. Hover the mouse back over the element to see the changed rule take effect.

Note that if you do it wrong in step 3 (if you use the mouse) you have to select a different element first before trying again.

Comment: Nice workaround. I doubt that Chrome developers intentionally did it this way but it does work this way. Thanks!

Comment: **But**: When you select *Inspect element* using keyboard... How do you get to styles then if you're not allowed to move the mouse?

Comment: One way is to make sure that *Inspect element* menu selection is already displayed in the dev tools area. Then you can easily click on it using a mouse and use mouse afterwards, while the element still stays in hover state, because browser didn't detect a mouse out. :) But I don't know how you get to editing styles after selecting *Inspect element*?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik You are allowed to move the mouse after you choose Inspect Element; even though the item becomes unhovered on the page, the CSS rule with the `:hover` pseudo-class is still visible and may be edited. After you change the rule, move the mouse back over the element on the page to see the changed rule taking effect.

Comment: +1 for finding a way around something that had to have been overlooked when they made the dev tools. Otherwise I am sure it wouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: @ryan You'll be pleased to know (as seen in the updated answer) that Chrome's developer tools now has a better way of forcing `:hover` for an element.

Answer (score 4):

(Chrome 22)

In the `Elements` panel, right-click the `.parent` element and select `Force Element State > :hover` in the context menu. Voila.

Alternatively, you can click the "pointer over a dotted rectangle" button in the `Styles` pane header at the right and check/uncheck pseudo-classes to be forced on the currently selected element.

Element state can now be forced on any elements in the DOM tree, not only the currently selected one.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the dev tools open and your looking at the style pane on the right side of the header bar where it says `Styles`, there is a plus button where you can add custom inspector-stylesheet rules. This may be what your looking for.