# Textbox's seem to blink after importing Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

After importing bootstrap CSS, my HTML textboxes are displaying off-center.

Before Bootstrap Import: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui5nq.png

After Bootstrap Import: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4W6U.png

The primary problem is when attempting to click one of the search results, the box disappears. This happens regardless of whether it is a plain CSS textbox, or a textbox styled with Bootstrap.

Fiddle:

Comment: Please include a fiddle for more specific help.

Comment: Are you importing Bootstrap after you have developed the style? Bootstrap is a framework which should be used at the beginning of a build. Any customisations should be done after the framework is in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you Bootstrap CSS is conflicting with your `:hover` class CSS for your search box.

Try inspecting the search box element using firebug or chrome, and forcing the state to `:hover`. Also look at your computed CSS rules for both states.

A [quick tutorial on forcing state.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392049/how-to-set-elements-hover-state-in-chrome-dev-tools-and-edit-childs-style)

Make sure you import Bootstrap before load any custom CSS, otherwise the Bootstrap behavior will overwrite the custom CSS.